# How to ask for user input with a default answer

Tags: fish

```
   read -p 'set_color green; echo -n "$prompt Do you like to succeed? [Y/n]: "; set_color normal' -l confirm
   
   switch $confirm
   case Y y ''
      command
   case N n
      return 1
```

So, I imagined `''` would allow us to press the `Enter` key and accept that as a yes.

And it does not. The documentation says sadly nothing about default values for reads.

How could I make this to accept a default input?

https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/read.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And it does not. The documentation says sadly nothing about default values for reads.

There is no default value for `read`. The variable will be filled by whatever was entered. If you press enter without first typing anything, it will just set the variable to the empty string - like `set foo ''`.

That means your suggested code works. Replacing the "command" and "return 1" with "echo yes" and "echo no", respectively, I do get "yes".

Comment: Oh yes. The output in my test was simply nothing ^-^